# How to redirect without a base path in vuejs using vitejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite, vue-router4

In fact, when it's the external link, I want to go to localhost:3000/profile/user but right now it's using localhost:3000/v2/profile/user so I don't want /v2/ if it's external.

I also tried with navigation guards in the router definition.

Here is my vite config :

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: '/v2/',
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

All my urls are with /v2/ at the end.

I try to redirect the user in a specific case using vue-router :

```js
// ....
setup() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const state = reactive({
      tabs: [
        {
          name: 'Booking',
          icon: 'fa-regular fa-calendar',
          external: false,
        },
        {
          name: 'Profil',
          icon: 'fa-solid fa-user',
          external: true,
          link: 'profile/user',
      }],
      currentTab: 'Dashboard',
    });

  function handleClickTab({ tab }) {
      const isExternal = get(tab, 'external');
      const tabName = get(tab, 'name');
      const tabLink = get(tab, 'link');
      if (isExternal) {
        router.push(tabLink);
        return;
      }
      router.push({ name: tabName });
      state.currentTab = tabName;
    }

  return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      handleClickTab,
  };
}
```

Comment: if `/v2/` doesn't apply as the base path of **all** your app routes, then `/v2/` simply shouldn't be the base.  use `/` instead and add `/v2/` to the routes that do require it.

Comment: The v2 is the basis for all routes. It concerns the migration of the application (total redesign). Routes that do not have /v2/ are used in the base application (the one to be migrated). So when I don't use /v2/ nginx takes care of redirecting to the original application folder. On the other hand, on the code side I have to indicate when I want v2 not to be used